# Could not extract Cloudera Hadoop VM archive

Tags: windows, hadoop, cloudera, 7zip

I am new to Cloudera. I have worked on hadoop previously, now I want to try Cloudera Hadoop. For this I started with Cloudera Hadoop VM.

The downloaded the file in 7zip format with 2GB size. When I try to extract, it shows error

```
Can not open file cloudera-quickstart-vm-4.4.0-1-vmware.7z as archive.
```

All other files are extracting properly but this single file is not extracting. I have downloaded the file three times but got the same error. Is there any specific way to extract this file?

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to do anything special, but I had to download the Standard QuickStart VirtualBox VM 3 times before the archive was complete. The final file that worked for me was actually ~2.6G in size.

Comment: I got. Problem was in my zip file. I downloaded it from wget command. Now every thing is fine.

Answer (score 0):

If Windows, you need to have `WinRar` installed. This seems to be a common problem while trying to use/install Cloudera QuickStart VM.